# Jenkins SVN Update only on manual build

Tags: java, svn, jenkins

I have some jobs in my Jenkins that trigger another one when they end.

Every job has an SVN Update task, because they can run separately.

Is there any possibility to skip the SVN Update when the Job was triggered by another job or only run the SVN Update when the build was queued manually?

Examples:

Current Workflow Automatic Build:

```
Start Job 1 -> SVN Update -> Build -> Trigger Build 2 -> SVN Update -> Build
```

Current Workflow Manual Build:

```
Start Job 2 -> SVN Update -> Build
```

Planned Automatic Workflow:

```
Start Job 1 -> SVN Update -> Build -> Trigger Build 2 -> Build
```

Planned Manual Workflow:

```
Start Job 2 -> SVN Update -> Build
```

Since you see I can't remove the SVN Update completely on Job 2 since it has to be done on the manual build.

Thanks for any help!